# Python - Looping through nested dictionaries and fetching values

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have the same format of nested dictionaries within a list. I am trying to iterate through every element and find the number of time we have values for `summary` as `through the API` and also count the number of assignees for `through the API`.

```
[{'id': '101',
 'type': 'log_file',
 'summary': 'Escalated to Mark through the API',
 'assignees': [{'id': 'xyz',
 'type': 'user_reference',
 'summary': 'Mark'}]},
 {'id': '102',
  'type': 'log_file',
  'summary': 'Escalated to Kevin by SMS',
  'assignees': [{'id': 'abc',
  'type': 'user_reference',
  'summary': 'Kevin'}]},
 {'id': '103',
  'type': 'log_file',
  'summary': 'Escalated to Scott through the API',
  'assignees': [{'id': 'pqr',
  'type': 'user_reference',
  'summary': 'Scott'}]}]
```

In the sample above, I expect a count of 2 for number of times `through the API` has returned for `summary` and the assignee value as `Mark and Scott` as these two different people have been assigned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a Pandas DataFrame:

```
df=pd.DataFrame(dd)
```

Count the number of appearances and put assignees names in a separate column:

```
df['summary'].str.contains('through the API').sum()
df['names'] = pd.Series([df.iloc[s,3][0]['summary'] for s in np.arange(0,df.shape[0])])
```

Comment: Right thanks dint strike me to convert this to a DataFrame

Answer (score 1):

You can just loop through the list. Here is my example:

```py
data = [{'id': '101', 'type': 'log_file', 'summary': 'Escalated to Mark through the API', 'assignees': [{'id': 'xyz', 'type': 'user_reference', 'summary': 'Mark'}]}, {'id': '102', 'type': 'log_file', 'summary': 'Escalated to Kevin by SMS', 'assignees': [{'id': 'abc', 'type': 'user_reference', 'summary': 'Kevin'}]}, {'id': '103', 'type': 'log_file', 'summary': 'Escalated to Scott through the API', 'assignees': [{'id': 'pqr', 'type': 'user_reference', 'summary': 'Scott'}]}]
people = [sum["assignees"][0]["summary"] for sum in data if "through the API" in sum["summary"]]   #This will return ["Mark", "Scott"]
number_of_assignees = len(people)    #This will return 2
```